# Can a particle transcribing motion described as $y=(\sin x)^2$ be called to be in vibration?

Tags: waves, oscillators, vibrations

I know that $\sin x$ or $\cos x$ curves can be said to be "in vibration," but what about $(\sin x)^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Vibration" just refers to oscillatory motion around an equilibrium point. $\sin^2(x)$ certainly satisfies this definition.

Also it's worth pointing out that $\sin^2(x)$ actually is a sinusoidal function
\begin{equation}
\sin^2(x) = \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2}
\end{equation}

Comment: which would the equilibrium point be?

Comment: The original question didn't provide any physical context. I could imagine using $\sin^2(x)$ to model oscillations around the average value of $1/2$. Another natural place it could show up is some kind of "bounce" away from and then return to $x=0$.

Comment: I just saw the identity! thanks